# How to prevent a Chrome extension from being made available in other .crx sites?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As already written in the title, I'd like to know if there is a way to prevent a Chrome extension from being made available in other .crx sites, but also if it's possible to prevent the download (e.g. by certain extensions and programs that allow you to download .crx files even directly in .zip format).

Comment: Interesting question but this is more suited for the [Google Chrome Extensions community](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions) where the Google Dev Relations team is also present. Right now, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Sachin, many thanks for pointing me to the Chrome Extensions Community.